# Looking for proper way to handle has_many through association in react-redux-rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have an application with rich client (react+redux) and rails 5 backend API.

In first approximation, we have 3 models

**issue.rb**

> has_many :issue_participants, dependent: :destroy
>
> has_many :participants, through: :issue_participants, class_name: 'User'

**issue_participant.rb**

> belongs_to :issue
>
> belongs_to :participant, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'

and **user.rb**

> has_many :issue_participants, dependent: :destroy
>
> has_many :issues, through: :issue_participants

I want to add participants to issue at frontend side. This will be happen in react component, where redux-form with user's collection will be render (only users, nothing else of current issue).

I choose from two options:

1. Update an issue with selected users via `IssuesController#update` action by passing `issues_participant_ids: []` to params. Please note that we have no this action right now, because it wasn't needed before today.
2. Create `IssueParticipant` records via `IssueParticipantsController#create` action.

Both options works. Which one should be given preference in the context of predictable consequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in favor of option number 1, because separate creation of related entities `issue_participants` generates problem with subsequent `issue` updates.

We should make additional request to know which users already related to issue, instead of take them from `issue` object if we work in context of `issue` form.

But if we generally update `issue_participants` as an `issue` attributes, we use default rails params behavior and remain within RoR framework convention.